# Can you install numpy_financial from Anaconda instead of pip?

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

The financial functions of numpy have been deprecated and will be removed from future versions.
They are now part of a new package called [numpy_financial](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/).

I understand it can be installed with pip, but I also understand that pip should be avoided whenever possible if you are running an Anaconda installation, as I am (is this true?).

So my question is: **is it possible to install numpy_financial through Anaconda?**

I have tried:

```
conda install numpy_financial
```

and

```
conda install -c conda-forge numpy_financial
```

but neither works - neither manages to find the package.

Answer (score 2):

Not yet.  But it's easy to build a package using these directions https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/building-conda-packages.html .  You make your own account on anaconda and build this package and upload it.  Afterwards it will be available to all.

```
conda install -c <your_account> numpy_financial
```

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that when using anaconda, you should always try first using `conda install xyz` before reverting to `pip install xyz` ([direct documentation reference](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#using-pip-in-an-environment)).

@Back2Basics is also correct that in the meantime, you can conda install. Official documentation is found [here](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/numpy-financial).

However, once numpy financial functions have been depreciated, you should rely on [their provided](https://numpy.org/numpy-financial/) pip install:

```sh
pip install numpy-financial
```